# How to select ip from db?

Tags: mysql, sql

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.0.1)) AS `id` FROM `survey_vote`' at line 1

```
   SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM survey_vote WHERE `pc` = INET_ATON(127.0.0.1)
```

Comment: Try to make ip number a string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to let `127.0.0.1` be string, jsut add `'`  before and after `127.0.0.1`

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM survey_vote WHERE `pc` = INET_ATON('127.0.0.1')
```

[INET_ATON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)